# Masking Password

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an application that as part of a call, returns a JSON string which apart from other details include the password.  Now, in this particular screen, when you're in view mode, I would like to show the password masked (*******) in a span, while if you click on the edit button, I show the password in an input field.

It is the first time I am using AngularJS for this, and tried to look if there's some filter that can help me in this, but didn't go too far.  Is there some other service that I would be able to use to just mask the password and show it in a span?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you can achieve this by doing :

```
//html
    <span ng-show="showpassword" type="password">{{password | passwordFilter}}</span>
    <input ng-hide="showpassword" type="password" ng-model="password">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="showpassword" ng-checked="false">

//js file
    app.filter('passwordFilter', function() {
      return function(input) {
        var split = input.split('');
        var result = "";
        for(var i = 0 ; i < split.length ; i++){
          result += "*";
        }
        return result;
      };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple filter to mask a string into some repeated char:

```
function passwordMask(aString) {
    return Array(aString.length + 1).join("*");
}

angular.module("someModule")
.filter("pwMask",function(){
    return passwordMask;
});
```

Then you could just use `{{password | pwMask}}` in your angular expressions.

Comment: @Arno_Geismar Thanks, fixed. You can also edit things like that yourself, Im happy to accept edits like that